# npm pack, include file from root folder of a package in a monorepo

Tags: npm, monorepo

I have a monorepo setup with some private packages and a couple of public packages that can be published. I have a few common files that are directly in the root folder. When I run `npm pack` I want to be able to pack a few common files from the root folder. Is there a way to do it? Creating symlinks didn't work. Providing '../../file' in `files` attribute of the package.json didn't work either (perhaps understandably as there is no way to specify the target location).

Note that I currently don't have lerna which seem to have special logic to temporarily copy the LICENSE.md file from root folder to the packages.

Looking for options other than manually creating a copy of the file in each package that can be published.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to accomplish this using prepack and postpack scripts